# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'"?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using Pyspark for writing this piece of code:

```
df.na.fill("").show()
# Refering columns by names
rdd2=df.rdd.map(lambda x: 
    (x.firstName+""+x.lastName,x.street+","+x.town,x.city,x.code) #error line
    )  
df2=rdd2.toDF(["name","address","city","code"])
df2.display()
```

I am getting error on line no 4 which says:

```
PythonException: 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str''
```

This is the output which i am getting for the csv file i am working on

[image]

I am using the function df.na to convert the null values to string, but it still shows the error for string and none type.
P.S: I am new to Pyspark so please help me out how can i avoid this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do:

```
df = df.na.fill("")
```

Otherwise it won't persist the conversion of none to string.